# Android parse notifications without app being in background?

Tags: android, parse-platform, notifications

I couldn't find a page or question where it can tell me how to make a notification without the app running in background or it being opened.
It would be great if anyone could help. (I'm using Android)

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @tinysunlight I'm trying to make my app get notifications from parse while the app is closed/not running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to create a Parse account and get your Application Id and Client Key.

After that you have to create your own custom Application class by creating a class that extends Application and then override onCreate (just like you would any activity) and place that line in.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
public void onCreate() {
    Parse.initialize(this, PARSE_APPLICATION_ID, PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
}
}
```

You also have to tell the manifest that you are using a custom application class. You can do this by, in your AndroidManifest.xml file, you will have to set the name element to the location of you new Application class:

```
<application
    android:name="com.packageName.example.MyApplication"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher_no_text" >
```

**In the Manifest file**

Declare the following permissions:

```
<permission android:name="com.packagename.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.packagename.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Also declare a `service` and `receiver` in the manifest:

```
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.packagename.android" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Change com.packagename to your package name too!

Finally go to your parse account and try sending a push notification from there.

Comment: @Archit Goel, I honestly didn't understand a thing from that tutorial, even though I did, it seems like I have to have a bunch of activities. I would like a simple way if possible.

Comment: @AliBdeir check my detailed answer. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: @AliBdeir the avtivities is provide by sdk.

Comment: @ArchitGoel Should I create a new Manifest file? Or should I put it in the <application> tag? Like: <application ...>....<application...></application></application>

Comment: Nope, in your default manifest file, declare these permissions